# Compensating for the Non-Persistence of Assignments within a Jinja2 Loop

Tags: jinja2

Per the [Assignments section](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#assignments) of the Jinja Docs, under the "Scoping Behavior" subsection:

> Please keep in mind that it is not possible to set variables inside a block and have them show up outside of it. This also applies to loops. The only exception to that rule are if statements which do not introduce a scope.

I understand the capabilities of the `else` statement in the `for` loop, and also special variables like `loop.index`, but these don't solve my problem.

I have a widget which outputs articles, but only if they match a certain criteria. To reduce the test case, here's a quick example code:

```
{% set maxiterations = 3 %}
{% set iterations = 0 %}
{% for item in seq %}
  {% if item == "bar" and iterations < maxiterations %}
    {{ item.foo }}
    {% set iterations = iterations + 1 %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This of course won't work: iterations will always equal `1`. `loop.index` won't help; I don't want to count iterations that were skipped. How can I address this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While @SumanKalyan is absolutely correct (you can't modify iterations inside the loop when it was set outside the loop), I found his solution, nor the `do` statement available in Jinja2 seem to be understood in my context.

Trying @SumanKalyan's suggestion or `do` always returned errors like:

```
CRITICAL: TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'iterations'.
Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'elif' or 'else' or 'endif'.
The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'if'.
```

The lack of support for `do` turned out to be because of the lack of this extension in my specific application ([Pelican](http://getpelican.com)). I could simply specify it, but instead I chose a different route. I found a different answer, assisted greatly by the realization that **Jinja2 `for` loops support conditional statements**. Thus:

```
{% set max_iterations = 3 %}
{% for item in seq if item == "bar" %}
    {% if index.loop < max_iterations %}
        {{ item.foo }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This satisfies a core part of the case: only output `item.foo` if `item == bar`; don't make it part of the subset of `seq` that's iterated over.

In my actual implementation (beyond the test case presented here), I had multiple conditions. One required skipping an item based on the truthiness of an externally-set variable and a particular loop iteration (the first one, as it happens). An example of how this is solved:

```
{% set baz == true %}
{% if baz %}
    {% set max_iterations = 4 %}
{% else %}
    {% set max_iterations = 3 %}
{% endif %}

{% for item in seq if item == "bar" %}
    {% if index.loop < max_iterations and not(baz and loop.index == 1) %}
        {{ item.foo }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

For the curious, the actual code (which is also [viewable in context](https://gitlab.com/tohuw/anew/blob/49614b53e948a4c54468fe023e8c8decff16eda3/templates/includes/articleswidget.html#L15-55)):

```
{# Only show the widget content if:
   - There a configured count of articles to display
   - There's any articles in articles_list
   - There's at least 2 articles...
   - ...Or at least 1 article if the widget count is set to 1 #}

{% if ARTICLES_WIDGET_COUNT and articles_list|length != 0 and (articles_list|length > 1 or ARTICLES_WIDGET_COUNT == 1) %}
    <aside class="siteFooter_articles widget">
        {% if ARTICLES_WIDGET_NAME %}
            <h1 class="widget_title">{{ ARTICLES_WIDGET_NAME }}</h1>
        {% endif %}

        <ol class="imageList list-noType">
            {# If this is the index page, the first article is always displayed.
            It gets skipped inside the loop, so increment the counter #}
            {% if isindex %}
                {% set max_iterations = ARTICLES_WIDGET_COUNT + 1 %}
            {% else %}
                {% set max_iterations = ARTICLES_WIDGET_COUNT %}
            {% endif %}

            {# Skip displaying this article if this is the page for the article being displayed in full
            If this isn't an article page, always display the item (note the additional condition below for index pages) #}
            {% for article in articles_list if article.url != thisarticle.url or thisarticle == null %}
                {# If this is the index page and the first loop iteration, the article to be displayed in the widget would be the same one
                displayed in full on the page. So, skip it. (Note the counter is incremented before the loop to account for this.) #}

                {% if not(loop.index == 1 and isindex) %}
                    {% set articles_widget = true %}
                    {% include 'includes/articleitem.html' %}
                {% endif %}

                {# If the set number of articles have been added to the widget, we're done here. #}
                {% if loop.index == max_iterations %} {% break %} {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </ol>

        <p class="readMore">
            <a class="readMore_link" href="{{ SITEURL }}/{{ ARTICLES_URL }}">More...</a>
        </p>
    </aside>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set 'iterations' outside the loop, you can't modify it inside the loop. 
You can defeat this behavior by using an object rather than a scalar for 'iterations':

```
{% set maxiterations = 3 %}
{% set iterations = [0] %}
{% for item in seq %}
  {% if item == "bar" and iterations[0] < maxiterations %}
    {{ item.foo }}
    {% iterations.append(iterations.pop() + 1) %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: When attempting this solution, I get: `CRITICAL: TemplateSyntaxError: Encountered unknown tag 'iterations'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'elif' or 'else' or 'endif'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'if'.`

Comment: I tried preceding the statement with `do`, but receive the same error, but this time the unknown tag is `do`. Is it likely this is a limitation of [Pelican](http://getpelican.com)?

Comment: Found out why that didn't work, at least with `do`... see my below answer.